# javascript calls within a table won't work

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript that increments an initial value with some number per second.  I can't seem to make the result of the script show up whenever I put the ID in a table row.

Here's the script:

```
<table class="dashboard_module" style="border-top:0;border-left:0; border-right:0;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var popcounter = document.getElementById('pop');
        var ethanolcounter = document.getElementById('ethanol');
        var meatlcounter = document.getElementById('meat');


        var Val1 = 1412015;
        var Val2 = 20000;
        var Val3 = 20000;


        setInterval( function() {
          Val1 += 1;
          Val2 +=1000;
          Val3 +=1000;

          popcounter.value = Math.round(Val1);
          ethanolcounter.value = Math.round( Val2 );
          meatlcounter.value = Math.round( Val3 );

        },1000);

    // -->   
    </script>
    <tr><td id="pop" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Pop</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td id="ethanol" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Etha</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td id="meat" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated M</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please add source here or make a fiddle at fiddle.jshell.net and share the link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the content of the td's using innerHTML. See my working jsBin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/IyavAPoN/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
    setInterval( function() {
      Val1 += 1;
      Val2 +=1000;
      Val3 +=1000;

      popcounter.innerHTML = Math.round(Val1);
      ethanolcounter.innerHTML = Math.round( Val2 );
      meatlcounter.innerHTML = Math.round( Val3 );

    },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table class="dashboard_module" style="border-top:0;border-left:0; border- right:0;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var Val1 = 1412015;
            var Val2 = 20000;
            var Val3 = 20000;


            setInterval( function() {
                var popcounter = document.getElementById('pop');
                var ethanolcounter = document.getElementById('ethanol');
                var meatlcounter = document.getElementById('meat');
                Val1 += 1;
                Val2 +=1000;
                Val3 +=1000;

                popcounter.innerHTML = Math.round(Val1);
                ethanolcounter.innerHTML = Math.round( Val2 );
                meatlcounter.innerHTML = Math.round( Val3 );

            },1000);
        </script>
        <tr>
        <td id="pop" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding:         0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%">
        </td>
        <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Pop</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td id="ethanol" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top;width:15%"></td>
        <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Etha</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td id="meat" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
        <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated M</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
        </td></tr>
    </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your script is on incorrect place. The browser parse your whole HTML code from top to down. If he finds `<script>` tags he runs them immideatly. So, when the browser comes to your first line in the script he trys to find the element with `id="pop"`, but he can not find that element, because this element is positioned on bottom of the script and is not yet parsed by browser.

You should always plase your scripts after the element which will be used by that script. Or you can add your script to the `window` events like `onload`: the script will be executed when the whole document is loaded.

Second of all, if want to see your calculated value in the table you shold use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.

```
<table class="dashboard_module" style="border-top:0;border-left:0; border-right:0;border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd">
    <tr><td id="pop" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Pop</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td id="ethanol" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated Etha</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td id="meat" class="label" style="font-weight: bold; color: green; padding: 0 10px 0 0; vertical-align: top; width:15%"></td>
    <td class="label" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px 0 0; width:35%; ; vertical-align: top">Estimated M</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus est congue luctus sodales.
    </td></tr>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var popcounter = document.getElementById('pop');
        var ethanolcounter = document.getElementById('ethanol');
        var meatlcounter = document.getElementById('meat');

        var Val1 = 1412015;
        var Val2 = 20000;
        var Val3 = 20000;

        setInterval( function() {
          Val1 += 1;
          Val2 +=1000;
          Val3 +=1000;

          popcounter.value = Math.round(Val1);
          ethanolcounter.value = Math.round( Val2 );
          meatlcounter.value = Math.round( Val3 );
        },1000);
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a total newbie to javascripting.  How do I implement sessionStorage to the above code such that it stores the incremented value and does not reset when the browser is refreshed.  Also how do I format my numbers to have commas.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helps you - please mark this as accepted :) If your numbers will have fraction - they will be automatically displayed with comma. You do not need to make type casting. Regarding sessioinStorage, the simplest way, I think, is to use `cookie`.